# R combinating vector

Tags: r

Suppose im have vector

```
c("A","B","C")
```

im need get list or vector combinating all variables( order is not important )

```
"A,B"
"A,C"
"B,C"
"A,B,C"
```

Comment: Maybe something like `unlist(sapply(2:length(x), function(i) combn(x, i, toString)))`

Comment: what about a expand.grid(c("A","B","C"), c("A","B","C"))

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
require(gtools)
all.perm <- sapply(1:length(letters),function(len){ 
  permutations(n = length(letters), r = len, v = letters)
})
```